# How to remove zip files in specific folder in my hosting by cron job?

Tags: cron

How to remove zip files in specific folder in my hosting by cron job?

**I want to remove zip files in specific folder every day at 5:00PM**

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a cronjob which will run at 5 PM daily which will find and remove all .zip files in the specified directory as:

> find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec rm -f {} \;

This will find all the `.zip` files in the current directory and remove them; this DOES not include directories named `*zip`

You can put the above command in a shell script as it is and then run it via cron.

To add a cron, simply put the following in the file that opens up after typing `crontab -e`:

> 0 17 * * * script.sh

Where `script.sh` is the script containing that one line command.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
This my cron job screen how I can use this command on it ? 
https://i.imgur.com/sHnXFt2.png

Comment: From the picture, the `Weekday` should have either 5 or 17 (consult with your hosting provider to clarify on that) and in the `Minute` field, it should be `00`. In the `Command` field, you need to put the command that I shared (`find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec rm -f {} \;`). Again, I'd recommend to ask your provider for how to set the time via GUI but the command should be the same.

Comment: Thank you for help I appreciate that my folder path is: public_html/ali/hi
How I can write the command ?

Comment: From the GUI, I am not sure but in order to search inside `public_html/ali/hi` when the command is called/run from `something/public_html/ali/hi`:
`find something/public_html/ali/hi -type f -name "*.zip" -exec rm -f {} \;`; you can also put in the absolute path (from the terminal, run `pwd` while you are cd'd into `...ali/hi` directory), the output is your absolute path to this directory. In this case, use: `find absolute_path_here -type f -name "*.zip" -exec rm -f {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

change folder_path to your value

1. crontab -e
2. $(which find) folder_path -maxdepth 0 -name "*.zip" -delete
3. save file (if vim :wq)

check cronjob installed:
crontab -l

Comment: Thank you for help but unfortunately not work!

Comment: Do you need exact values that you can use in your GUI? 
Did you change folder_path to the path of your choice? What is a full path of the directory you need to remove files from?